# How to Display value of textbox in label in another form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Hi I'm new to C# and I want to display the value of my textBox1 in form1 to my Label1 in form2. I tried using this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = textBox1.Text;

        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

But it didn't work because it's in another form. Can someone tell me how to do it right?

Comment: You have a few ways to do this. One, you could change the constructor for `Form2` to take a string. Pass it `textBox1.Text` when you create the `Form2` then in the constructor itself assign the value to the label. Other method would be to set a `public` value on `Form1` that just returns `textBox1.Text` and read that from `Form2`, but this is a bit more convoluted and less nice IMO. Just google "How to pass value between forms", this is likely going to get closed as a duplicate because of this.

Comment: have you considered creating a common static class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In form1 write this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 form = new Form2(TextBox1.Text);
        form.Show();
    }
```

In form2 write this

```
public Form2(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: The method inside form2 auto generated & called constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
 // In Form1.cs.
private Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
private void GetOtherFormTextBox()
{
    textBox1.Text = otherForm.label1.Text;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    GetOtherFormTextBox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

In form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.LabelText = "My Text";
    from.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Form 2

```
private string labelText;
public string LabelText { get { return labelText; } set { labelText = value; } }
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = LabelText;
}
```